# Need to implement javascript valiadation in Datalist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datalist

Hi I have my page layout as below image showing

[image]

What I want is on click of Sizing checkbox inner radio button get auto checked and on click on stone resetting the inner radio button list get an auto check.

My HTML code looks like

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtbindjewellery" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="dtbindjewellery_ItemDataBound" Width="100%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 jewelerymain">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="Servicechkbox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ServiceName")%>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdserviceid" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ServiceId")%>' />                                    
                            </div>
                 <%-- Sizing Radiobutton--%>                                 
                        <div id="divsizing" runat="server" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 subservices" visible="false">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdsizing1" runat="server" GroupName="ringsize" />                                
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddselectSize" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <br />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdsizing2" runat="server" GroupName="ringsize" />                                
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtsize" runat="server" CssClass="txtNumericUpDownExtender"></asp:TextBox>

                        </div>
                       <%-- Stone resetting Radiobutton--%>                                 
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiosub" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>                   
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

here sizing had 2 unique radio button and stone resetting has radio button list.

I bind it on basis of different ids and the Id of checkbox and radio get changes in the data list.

**How should I place validation on checkbox click in javascript?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below.

```
 function Specialinstruction() {
        var datalist = document.getElementById("<%=dtbindjewellery.ClientID%>");
        var count = datalist.rows.length;

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var chkid = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_Servicechkbox_' + i);
            //var checkboxid = document.getElementById(id);
            if (chkid.checked == true) {
                // alert("hello");
                var hdservice = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_hdserviceid_' + i);
                var value = hdservice.value;

                if (value == 3) {
                    var rdsizing1 = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_rdsizing1_' + i);
                    var rdsizing2 = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_JewelleryServices_dtbindjewellery_rdsizing2_' + i);
                    if (rdsizing1.checked == false && rdsizing2.checked == false)
                    { rdsizing1.checked = true; }
                }
}
}

   <asp:CheckBox ID="Servicechkbox" CssClass="cb" onClick="Specialinstruction();" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ServiceName")%>' />
```